# Ace editor - how do I remove/reset indent?

Tags: ace-editor

I want to change the behavior of the editor such that when the user presses enter on an empty list bullet, their cursor position is reset to the start of the line (rather than leaving them at the indented amount).

I've tried:

`aceEdit.moveCursorTo(rowToUpdate, 0)`

`aceEdit.getSession().indentRows(rowToUpdate, rowToUpdate, "")`

`aceEdit.getSession().replace(range(rowToUpdate, 0, rowToUpdate, 0), "")`

However, all three of these leave the cursor at the previous indent level. How do I reset the indent level for the line?

---

Update: adding example.

```
* list
    * list 
    * list
    *                  <- user presses enter here
     _
```

Cursor is where I placed the underscore above, and can't be reset programmatically to the start of the line using what I listed above. (User can backspace the indents to get back to the start.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `editor.setOption("enableAutoIndent", false)` to disable automatic indentation.

If you want a way to keep autoIndent in all cases except the list, try creating an issue on ace's github page

If you want to remove the indentation on particular line you can do

```js
var range = ace.Range
var cursor = editor.getCursorPosition()
var line = editor.session.getLine(cursor.row)
var match = /^\s*\*\s*/
if (match) {
    editor.session.replace(new Range(cursor.row, 0, cursor.row, cursor.column), "")
}
```

Comment: I like the automatic indentation though - in lists it's great. I just want to reset indentation on a specific row.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "resetting indentation" could you show an example of a line before and after?

Comment: @a user Sure, I added an update above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a custom mode, you can give it a custom `$outdent` and related methods - see [MatchingBraceOutdent](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/src/mode/matching_brace_outdent.js), for example. I think the full set of indentation-related Mode methods is:

- getNextLineIndent
- checkOutdent
- autoOutdent